# Scroll Lateral GridPanel ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema:
    En el siguiente código necesito que aparezca el scroll lateral para dos de los grid panel, y por mucha prueba que haga no se como solucionarlo. Alguna idea?

```
 oThis.fileGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
                id: oThis.CLASS_NAME+'_fileGrid',
                header: false,
                hideHeaders: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                viewConfig : {
                   style : {
                    overflow : 'auto',
                    overflowX : 'hidden'
                  }
                },
                store: oThis.fileStore,
                  columns:[{
                    dataIndex: 'icon',
                    flex: 2,
                    renderer: function(value, p, record) {
                        if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".")<0){
                            return '';
                        }
                        if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".pdf")>-1){
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/PDF.png" style="height:2.5em"></img>';
                        } else if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".doc")>-1 || record.data.fileName.indexOf(".docx")>-1){
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/ms-word.png" style="height:2.5em"></img>';
                        } else if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".xls")>-1 || record.data.fileName.indexOf(".xlsx")>-1){
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/ms-excel.png" style="height:2.5em"></img>';
                        } else if(record.data.fileName.indexOf("ppt")>-1 || record.data.fileName.indexOf(".pptx")>-1){
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/ms-ppt.png" style="height:2.5em"></img>';
                        } else if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".png")>-1 || record.data.fileName.indexOf(".jpg")>-1){
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/jpg-icon.png" style="height:2.5em"></img>';
                        } 
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/file-icon.png" style="height:2.5em"></img>';
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        click: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
                            if(dv.store.data.items[item].data.idAlfresco != -1){
                                oThis.showAttachment(dv.store.data.items[item].data.idAlfresco);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  },{
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 15,
                    renderer: function(value, p, record) {
                        if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".")<0){
                            return '<b>'+COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME,"noAdjuntos")+'</b>';
                        }
                        p.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="'+record.data.fileName+'"';
                        return '<b>'+COREProxy.languageMng.getText(oThis.CLASS_NAME,"fileName")+':&nbsp</b>'+record.data.fileName;
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        click: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
                            if(dv.store.data.items[item].data.idAlfresco != -1){
                                oThis.showAttachment(dv.store.data.items[item].data.idAlfresco);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    id:oThis.CLASS_NAME+'_attachmentDeleteColumn',
                    hidden: this.hasComponentPermission(oThis.CLASS_NAME+'_attachmentDeleteColumn'),
                    dataIndex: 'delete',
                    flex: 1,
                    renderer: function(value, p, record) {
                        if(record.data.fileName.indexOf(".")<0){
                            return '';
                        }else{
                            return '<img src="'+COREProxy.blackboard.urlbaseApp + '/img/close.png" style="cursor:pointer"></img>';
                        }               
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        click: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
                            if(dv.store.data.items[item].data.idAlfresco != -1){
                                oThis.deleteAttachment(dv.store.data.items[item].data.idAlfresco, oThis.tipoAdjunto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Hola Exferos, puedes explicar mejor lo de *"por mucha prueba que haga no se como solucionarlo."*? Es una explicacion muy vaga. Por favor indica qué has intentado y los problemas que te surjen : errores, resultado no esperado..?Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. un saludo

Comment: Buenas y gracias por responder, he mirado por internet algunos ejemplos y he ido probando, por ejemplo, poner lo de viewConfig y editar el tipo de layout pero el resultado es el mismo siempre, me carga todo bien con los datos pero no me sale el scroll lateral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido arreglar mi problema, el código que había publicado es insuficiente para resolver este caso ya que ese grid panel es hijo de otro panel lo que quiere decir que obviamente el autoscroll no iba a funcionar. Al darme cuenta y meterle al padre el autoscroll: true a funcionado exactamente como quería. Disculpen las molestias.